# Appium gets too slow while testing React Native app

Tags: python, appium, ui-automation

I am testing a React Native app using Appium in Python. This is the first time seeing that the app responds too slow with Appium but works completely fine while testing manually. Any idea on how to improve speed of tests?

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve test speed is use a modern device. For your issue, because the app runs well without also running appium doesn't mean the device is not the culprit. Appium does run on the device while also running the app, so the device needs to be able to run both the app and other apps at the same time well to be able to run smooth appium tests.

Comment: This is not an answer, make a comment instead

Comment: The thing is, I have tried that app on multiple devices and the result was same. Even a simple click on a button took almost a minute to execute, even while using python idle shell. This is my first time facing this issue so no ideas whats going on.

Comment: Anything going on in the appium logs during that minute?

Comment: When the command is executed, the appium logs show element being matched but then go silent until that click happens.